# How to find the closest date from current date from a multi-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

### Question

I have the following multi-dimensional array where `slot_date` is coming from the database query. I have a button for every `student_id`. But I need only one button for the closest date.

**Output in Ajax call**

```
[
  '1': {
    slot_date: "2019-01-11"
    student_id: 26
  }
  '2': {
    slot_date: "2019-01-21"
    student_id: 27
  }
  '3': {
    slot_date: "2019-03-11"
    student_id: 28
  }
  '4': {
    slot_date: "2019-03-18"
    student_id: 29
  }
]
```

**Javascript file**

```js
join_button = '<a onclick="studentJoinMeeting()"><button class="ongoing-btn">Join Meeting</button></a>';
```

**Desired Output**

I need the id of date `2019-03-11` i.e closest date to current date. I need the join button only on that `2019-03-11` date.

Comment: This is not a multidimensional array. And your question is as is unclear, what do you want to achieve exactly? Please edit your question appropriately.

Comment: Cast to date objects. Get unix time. The closest date is the date with the smaller absolute value after subtracting the target date from the comparison date. Or just order the dates and take the date after the target date.

Comment: Since you are using key/value pairs in your data, you should be using an object instead of an array, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your array based on the dates, by calculating their absolute distance to today. You can then take the first element.

I modified your data array to be a data object since your are using key/values pairs.

```js
const data = {
  '1': {
    slot_date: "2019-01-11",
    student_id: 26
  },
  '2': {
    slot_date: "2019-01-21",
    student_id: 27
  },
  '3': {
    slot_date: "2019-03-11",
    student_id: 28
  },
  '4': {
    slot_date: "2019-03-18",
    student_id: 29
  }
};

const today = Date.now();

// This function returns the absolute difference in ms between 2 dates
const dateAbsoluteDiff = (date1, date2) => {
  if (date1 - date2 < 0) return date2 - date1;
  else                   return date1 - date2;
};

// get the entries (array of key/values) of the data, sort them based
// on their date distance to today
// take the first element (the closest), this is a key/value pair
// return the second item from this pair, which is the original object
const closest = Object.entries(data).sort((e1, e2) => {
  return dateAbsoluteDiff(new Date(e1[1].slot_date), today) -
         dateAbsoluteDiff(new Date(e2[1].slot_date), today);
})[0][1];


console.log(closest);
console.log('Student id:', closest.student_id);
```

If your input data was instead an array, you can sort it directly:

```
const data = [{
  slot_date: "2019-01-11",
  student_id: 26
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-01-21",
  student_id: 27
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-03-11",
  student_id: 28
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-03-18",
  student_id: 29
}];

const closest = data.sort((e1, e2) => {
  return dateAbsoluteDiff(new Date(e1.slot_date), today) -
         dateAbsoluteDiff(new Date(e2.slot_date), today);
})[0];
```

If instead you want to get the next closest date, then don't take the absolute difference, map your array to an array containing the differences, then sort them and find the first difference greater or equal to 0.

```js
const data = [{
  slot_date: "2019-01-11",
  student_id: 26
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-01-21",
  student_id: 27
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-03-11",
  student_id: 28
}, {
  slot_date: "2019-03-18",
  student_id: 29
}];

const today = Date.now();

const nextDate = data
  .map(({ slot_date }) => ({ slot_date, diff: new Date(slot_date) - today }))
  .sort((e1, e2) => e1.diff - e2.diff)
  .find(date => date.diff >= 0)

console.log(nextDate.slot_date)
```

Comment: I am getting the previous closest date from my array. I will share you my array in below

Comment: [{"slot_date": "2019-01-08"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-09"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-10"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-11"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-21"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-11" },{"slot_date": "2019-03-18"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-25"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-01"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-08"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-15"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-22"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-29"},{"slot_date": "2019-05-06"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-07"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-14"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-21"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-28"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-04"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-11"}]

Comment: this is my array
[{"slot_date": "2019-01-08"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-09"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-10"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-11"},{"slot_date": "2019-01-21"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-11" },{"slot_date": "2019-03-18"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-25"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-01"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-08"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-15"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-22"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-29"},{"slot_date": "2019-05-06"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-07"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-14"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-21"},{"slot_date": "2019-03-28"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-04"},{"slot_date": "2019-04-11"}]

Comment: Please help ASAP.

Comment: I have added the code to get the next closest date, please have a look. I have tested with your new data and it works

Comment: I have this array in php. How will i do the same (closest date to cuurent date in php)
[1=>[slot_date "2019-01-11",student_id=> 26],2=>[slot_date=> "2019-01-13",student_id=> 21],3=>[slot_date=> "2019-01-15",student_id=> 1],4=>[slot_date=> "2019-01-16",student_id=> 2],5=>[slot_date=> "2019-02-01",student_id=> 6],6=>[slot_date=> "2019-02-11",student_id=> 126],7=>[slot_date=> "2019-03-07",student_id=> 216],
]

Comment: If this is working fine, can you accept the answer? :)

Answer (score 1):

You given array is not valid. Arrays cannot have keys. You cant write `key:value` in `[]` use `{}` for that. Here is example with array.
And closest date to current date will the highest date and it will be `2019-03-18`

```
let arr = [{slot_date: "2019-01-11",student_id: 26},
           {slot_date: "2019-01-21",student_id: 27},
           {slot_date: "2019-03-11",student_id: 28},
           {slot_date: "2019-03-18",student_id: 29},
]
let maxDate = 0;
let maxDateID;
for(let item of arr){
    if(new Date(item.slot_date) > maxDate){
        maxDate = new Date(item.slot_date);
        maxDateID = item.student_id;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will give you the 2019-03-18. But I need 2019-03-11 because the closest date to the current date is 2019-03-11 not 2019-03-18.